# Cannot get Ajax to return html

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am learning jQuery on codeschool. All the way through the ajax lessons i could not get it to work. 
Please can somebody give me a push in the right direction.
Thanks in advance.

Here is a jsfiddle..

https://jsfiddle.net/w202usyk/

and here is my code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>Where's Aggie???</title>

  <script type="text/javascript"    src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <link type="text/css" href="main2.css" rel="stylesheet">

 </head>

<body>

    <button class="btn"> Click Here</button>
    <div class='headbox'>
      <p class='main-title'>A</p>
    </div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="application2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My js..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').on('click', '.btn', function(){
    $.ajax('http://www.jamesleetaylor.com/wheresaggie/b.html', {
          success: function(response) {
        $('.main-title').replaceWith(response);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

and CSS

```
.btn {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.main-title {
    text-align: center;
}

.headbox {
    width: 100px;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Is this call being made from a page opened on same domain and with www in address?

Comment: fixed it using a relative link. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are getting the error: `[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.jamesleetaylor.com/wheresaggie/b.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` because you need to allow access to your website.

Comment: can you explain how to allow access?